# How can I use SelectMany on my IQueryable of classes?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been struggling on this for a whole day now.

So my class looks like follows:

```
public class SupplierSummaryReport {
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public decimal TurnOverValues { get; set; }
}
```

The LINQ so far looks like this:

```
var data = (from i in _ctx.Invoices
                        where i.Turnover == true
                        where last5Years.Contains(i.InvoiceDate.Year)
                        select new {
                            Year = i.InvoiceDate.Year,
                            AccountName = i.AccountName,
                            Value = i.NetAmount_Home ?? 0
                        });

            var y = data.GroupBy(r => new { r.Year, r.AccountName })
               .Select(g => new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport {
                   SupplierName = g.Key.AccountName,
                   TurnOverValues = new List<decimal>{
                   g.Sum(r => r.Value)
                   } 
               });
```

This gives me data which looks like this:

```
{2014, "Test Supplier", 1}, {2012, "Test Supplier", 2}, {2015, "Test Supplier two", 5}, {2011, "Test Supplier two", 9}
```

I need to use `.SelectMany` to select the `SupplierName` and the `TurnOverValues`. However I need to put these values into a separate list of classes like follows:

```
public class SupplierSummaryData {
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I've been looking to use LINQ but I haven't been able to do it thus far. I understand that this issue is very specific but I have no where else to turn, if you need more information, please leave a comment.

Expected output:

```
{"Test Supplier", {2,5}}, {"Test Supplier two", {5,6}}
```

Comment: `SupplierSummaryData` does not contain a year. Does that mean that you don't want to group by the year also? Can you show an example of the expected output?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Hi, I do not need the year at the moment, no. Check edit for expected outcome

Comment: In your example you're assigning `SupplierSummaryReport.TurnOverValues` a `List` yet its defined as a `decimal` - that cannot compile (I assume its just a copy/paste error?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group by the `AccountName` only and then for each group select the Supplier Name and the list of values like this:

```
var result =
    data.GroupBy(r => r.AccountName)
    .Select(g => new APData.Audit.Models.ReportModels.SupplierSummaryReport
    {
        SupplierName = g.Key,
        TurnOverValues = g.Select(r => r.Value).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: That is an extremely valid point. However I receive OutOfMemoryExceptions due to the mass amount of data. Oh well. Onto another issue. Thanks!